# MLE for the number of samples given $k$ largest values

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, extreme-value

I have the views on the top 100 videos using a tag in TikTok and want to estimate the total number of videos in that tag. I know the distribution for other tags so I can make a guess as to what it is for this one, but I don't know for sure.

One formal model of this: I'm given the $k$ largest of $n$ i.i.d. samples, and I wish to estimate $n$.

Let $F(v)=p(X\leq v)$. Then I believe that the probability of having exactly $k$ of $n$ samples greater than $v$ is binomially distributed as $B(n, k, F(v))$.

So I think one way I could solve this is to set $v$ to be the smallest of the $k$ samples, and then find the value of $n$ which maximizes the likelihood. Is this the best way to solve the problem? I feel like I'm not using all of the relevant information.

Also, empirically it doesn't seem to give a very good estimate: you can see that there is some correlation here, but it's pretty weak:

[image]

Code to produce image:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.special import comb
import pandas as pd

def run_test(size, k = 10):
    data = norm.rvs(size = size)
    biggest = sorted(data)[-k]

    def score(n):
        l = 1 - norm.cdf(biggest)
        return -binom.logpmf(k, n, l)
    
    fitted = optimize.minimize(score, x0 = 10, method = 'Nelder-Mead',
               options={'xatol': 1e-8})
    return fitted.x

sizes = np.random.randint(low = 100, high = 10000, size = 500)
estimates = [run_test(s) for s in sizes]
plt.scatter(sizes, estimates)
plt.xlabel('true size')
plt.ylabel('estimated size')
```

Comment: What is the practical context? Do you **know** the true distribution function $F$?

Comment: I have the views on the top 100 videos using a tag in TikTok and want to estimate the total number of videos in that tag. I know the distribution for other tags so I can make a guess as to what it is for this one, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Data from one tag isn’t enough for this problem. Eg: Suppose each tag is a mixture, with a fraction $v$ of viral videos that travel widely and $1-v$ of videos mostly seen in one community. The top 100 videos in each tag are all viral, so they don’t help in estimating $v$ and they provide only a lower bound for $n$. We’d need to know more about the distribution for other tags to answer the question.